# unsigned integer devision rounding AVR GCC

Tags: rounding, avr, avr-gcc, unsigned-integer, floor

I am struggling to understand how to divide an unsigned integer by a factor of 10 accounting for rounding like a float would round.

```
uint16_t val = 331 / 10; // two decimal to one decimal places 3.31 to 3.3

uint16_t val = 329 / 10; // two decimal to one decimal places 3.29 to 3.3 (not 2.9)
```

I would like both of these sums to round to 33 (3.3 in decimal equivalent of 1 decimal place)

Im sure the answer is simple if i were more knowledgable than i am on how processors perform integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since integer division rounds the result downward to zero, just add half of the divisor, whatever it is. I.e.:

`uint16_t val = ((uint32_t)x + 5) / 10; // convert to 32-bit to avoid overflow`

or in more general form:

```
static inline uint16_t divideandround(uint16_t quotient, uint16_t divisor) {
  return ((uint32_t)quotient + (divisor >> 1)) / divisor;
}
```

If you are sure there will no 16-bit overflow (i.e. values will always be not more than 65530) you can speed up the calculation by keeping values 16 bit:

`uint16_t val = (x + 5) / 10;`

Comment: yes im sure it wont overflow, the values are from ADC reads that don't go anywhere near there boundary's, the whole reason for using uint16 is performance so i don't want to cast it. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked it out, This seems to give me the right answer, please let me know if I am actually wrong and it fails.

```
uint16_t val = 329;
if (val%10>=5)
{
    val = (val+5)/10;
}
else
{
    val = val/10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one 16-bit divmod operation:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t udiv10_round (uint16_t n)
{
    uint16_t q = n / 10;
    uint16_t r = n % 10;
    return r >= 5 ? q + 1 : q;
}
```

When you are optimizing for size (`-Os`), avr-gcc will compute both quotient and remainder by means of one library call to `__udivmodhi4`.

When you are optimizing for speed (`-O2`), avr-gcc might avoid<sup>1</sup> `__udivmodhi4` altogether and instead perform a 16×16=32 multiplication with a factor of `0xcccd`, so that the quotient and remainder are easy to compute from the high part of that product.

---

<sup>1</sup>This happens if the MCU you are compiling for supports `MUL`.  If `MUL` is nor supported, avr-gcc still uses divmod operation as a 16×16=32 multiplication would not gain anything.